# multiple sort table using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Any clue why this code won't be able to do sorting properly base on columns?

```
sort(key){
    this.setState({
      [`toggle-${key}`]: !this.state[`toggle-${key}`],
      data: sortBy(this.state.data, [key], this.state[`toggle-${key}`]).map(v => v)
    })
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <table>
          <thead>
            {Object.keys(this.state.data[0]).map(v => {
              return(
                <th onClick={()=>this.sort(v)}>
                  {v.toUpperCase()}
                </th>
              )
              })}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.data.map(v=>{
              return(
                <tr>
                  <td>{v.id}</td>
                  <td>{v.name}</td>
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The toggling of the state seems to be correct but the reflection is only happening for the first time.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zqno7m7j4p

Comment: @KyleRichardson the 3rd argument isn't true and false? added a demo, I need to sorting to be able to toggle.

Comment: The third argument is supposed to represent the `this` value that you want indices of. Your code seems to be working as is though. The sandbox seems to work just fine. Sorting on both rows is working.

Comment: @KyleRichardson working but it can't toggle, I expect it to toggle. or I should use orderBy instead of sortBy?

Comment: So you want to be able to flip the order from asc to dsc and back in a column? I'll be back in a few.

Comment: Yes if you want to be able to asc and dsc you will need to use `.orderBy`. `.sortBy` will always be in asc order.

Comment: Refer to Ori's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash's `_.sortBy()` doesn't have the ability to select descending or ascending. Use [`_.orderBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy) instead ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z2pnykl424)):

```
sort(key) {
  const columnState = !this.state[`toggle-${key}`];

  this.setState({
    [`toggle-${key}`]: columnState,
    data: orderBy(
      this.state.data,
      [key],
      columnState ? 'desc' : 'asc'
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: great! this is it. But I think it should be `columnState ? 'asc' : 'desc'`

Comment: Choose what you prefer. I didn't select `asc` : `desc` because the 1st click on `id` won't show any change.